# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::SessionStore with gem 'activerecord-session_store'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We are upgrading Rails 3.2 engine to Rails 4.2.0 on ruby 2.0.0. Gem 'activerecord-session_store' was added to engine's gemspec following gem's instruction:

```
 s.add_dependency 'activerecord-session_store'
```

and added following in initializers/session_store.rb under dummy:

```
Dummy::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, :key => '_my_app_session'
```

then, we did `bundle install`. When we ran:

```
bundle exec rails generate active_record:session_migration
```

There is the error from the gem's generator:

```
/activerecord-session_store-0.1.1/lib/generators/active_record/session_migration_generator.rb:16:in `session_table_name': uninitialized co
nstant ActiveRecord::SessionStore (NameError).
```

We move the gem into engine's Gemfile and same error. Why the SessionStore is still not initialized?

### Update

In engine's engine.rb under lib, the session table is pointed to:

```
initializer "Authentify.add_middleware" do |app|
  ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.table_name = 'authentify_sessions'
  app.middleware.use ActiveRecord::SessionStore
end
```

The setup works for Rails 3.2.

Comment: Since this is a upgrading from 3.2 to 4.2, the session table has been created already. I am wondering if rails g migration activerecord:session_migration needs to be ran at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you were not using the default table name for sessions, set:

```
ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session.table_name = 'your_old_session_table'
```

in `config/application.rb`.

Additional [configuration](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store#configuration).

Comment: please see updated post. The exactly same line is in engine.rb under /lib in our case.

Comment: The error indicates that it can not find ::SessionStore

Comment: Do you have a `require 'activerecord-session_store'` ?

Comment: Where do we add 'require activerecord-session_store'?

Comment: Try in your `engine.rb` under `lib`.

Comment: Tried in engine.rb require 'activerecord-session_store' under module and class. Both of them received "`require': cannot load such file -- activerecord-session_store (LoadError)". We also tried in application.rb under dummy and the same error. Is there other place we can try?

Comment: In engine.rb add `require 'active_record/session_store'`

Answer (score 1):

What we did is to add gem 'activerecord-session_store' to engine's Gemfile in addition to the .gemspec. The error disappeared.